# How do I dynamically change ContentTemplate based on bound property?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been having an issue that has been plaguing me for a while now, but I believe I finally tracked it down.  The symptoms are that my WPF controls will not render correctly when one of my bound properties triggers a `DataTrigger` that swaps out the `ContentTemplate`. Stack trace:

```
  System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
  Parameter name: d
     at MS.Internal.Data.ElementObjectRef.GetObject(DependencyObject d, ObjectRefArgs args)
     at MS.Internal.Data.ObjectRef.GetDataObject(DependencyObject d, ObjectRefArgs args)
     at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.MS.Internal.Data.IDataBindEngineClient.VerifySourceReference(Boolean lastChance)
     at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.Task.Run(Boolean lastChance)
     at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.Run(Object arg)
     at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.OnLayoutUpdated(Object sender, EventArgs e)
     at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireLayoutUpdateEvent()
     at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
     at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
     at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.InvokeOnRenderCallback.DoWork()
     at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
     at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
     at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
     at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
     at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

Debugger doesn't help at all since it just breaks on `application.Run()`.  Here's what I'm doing in terms of the actual xaml:

```
  <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SomeCollectionView"
                        Source="{Binding StatsByUser}"
                        IsLiveSortingRequested="True">
      <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
          <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Amount" Direction="Descending"/>
          <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Name" Direction="Ascending"/>
      </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
  </CollectionViewSource>

  <ItemsControl Background="Transparent" Width="{StaticResource Width}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SomeCollectionView}}">
      <ItemsControl.Resources>
          <DataTemplate x:Key="FullViewTemplate">
              <Border Style="{StaticResource BorderStyle}">
                  <controls:FullCustomEntityControl CustomEntityObject="{Binding}"
                                                  Style="{StaticResource PanelStyle}"
                                                  MouseDown="Info_OnMouseDown"/>
              </Border>
          </DataTemplate>
          <DataTemplate x:Key="CompactViewTemplate">
              <Border Style="{StaticResource BorderStyle}">
                  <controls:CompactCustomEntityControl CustomEntityObject="{Binding}"
                                                     Style="{StaticResource PanelStyle}"
                                                     MouseDown="Info_OnMouseDown"/>
              </Border>
          </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.Resources>
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                  <ContentControl.Style>
                      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                          <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource FullViewTemplate}"/>
                          <Style.Triggers>
                              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=c:ShellView}, Path=ViewModel.ShowCompactView}" Value="True">
                                  <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CompactViewTemplate}"/>
                              </DataTrigger>
                          </Style.Triggers>
                      </Style>
                  </ContentControl.Style>
              </ContentControl>
          </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
```

Whenever `ViewModel.ShowCompactView` raises `PropertyChanged` event and kicks off the `DataTrigger`, it will switch the `ContentTemplate`, which then throws this error.  Is there a way to fix this or a better way to architect the `ContentTemplate` swap that won't result in this?

Edit: Potentially relevant support article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2461678

Edit2: Example of what happens to the UI: [image].  You can see the large slots are the `FullCustomEntityControl` and the small slots are `CompactCustomEntityControl`.  Leaving them in either mode without changing it does not result in any issues, but having the data trigger change them results in issues like this.  Also, the control used should be consistent, not what seems like to be a split here. By leaving them in either mode, I meant just removing the data trigger and choosing one or the other.

Edit3: A post on a similar issue with someone from Microsoft responding: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fb4d0f41-bfea-409f-b8ac-e66558984b7a/argumentnullexception-when-displaying-wpf-window?forum=wpf

Relevant information:

> If you're getting an ArgumentNullException with VerifySourceReference on the stack, it is definitely caused by the issue described in Connect 561752.   Even if your app is not using ElementName bindings directly, it may use them indirectly - several built-in controls use ElementName bindings:  ComboBox, ContextMenu, MenuItem, etc.

Comment: I'm curious if having two `ItemsControl` with visibility binding would be effective.  Is there additional processing overhead even if the control is not visible?

Comment: Changing the `ContentTemplate` is a solid solution for this and should not result in `ArgumentNullException` by itself. The problem can come from your controls `CompactCustomEntityControl ` and `FullCustomEntityControl`. [Enable Thrown CLR Exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx) and you can get the actual place the exception is thrown in VS debug.

Comment: I tried recreating your issue, with simplified example (removed your custom controls, CollectionViewSource etc...), and everything seems to work - it does switch my TextBox template with my TextBlock template... I suggest you'd try to create simple example and add the missing pieces from there until you find the real root cause

Comment: @AmittaiShapira How many elements are in the collection that you're binding to?  When the problem occurs, what happens is that the control that it breaks on just shows up as a blank space where it would normally be.  Other elements of the collection that did bind correctly are showing up without issue.

Comment: I've also added in a potentially relevant support link that seems related, but I have doubts that it's the cause since my version is 18402 while the hotfix version is 395.  Unfortunately, that dll is no longer available to download so I have no real way to test if it's a regression issue.

Comment: @NovitchiS I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding something, but isn't my stack trace the exact location where it was thrown?  Do I need to grab pdb's for the framework in order to debug this more deeply?

Comment: Try putting both custom controls into the same DataTemplate (say "FullViewTemplate") and see if both templates are rendered for every list item. I'm just curious, in case the problem lies with binding both custom controls to the same object.

Comment: @AndrewStephens I'll give that a try tonight and let you know.

Comment: @AndrewStephens Zero problems having both.

Answer (score 1):

Every ItemsControl has **[ItemTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx)** property, You can take help of this.

Comment: As far as I know, `ItemTemplateSelector` only performs the selection once.  In my example, the template gets updated when the bound variable changes.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know, whether i understood the question wrong , but when i copied the codes to my solution it worked perfectly. below is my change,

One thing i did was, Replaced Path=ViewModel.ShowCompactView with Path=DataContext.ShowCompactView , and relativesource is my MainWindow,

```
<ItemsControl Background="Transparent" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SomeCollectionView}}">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="FullViewTemplate">
                <Border >
                    <Label Content="{Binding}"
                                              />
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="CompactViewTemplate">
                <Border >
                    <Button Content="{Binding}"
                                                />
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                    <ContentControl.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource FullViewTemplate}"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext.ShowCompactView}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CompactViewTemplate}"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ContentControl.Style>
                </ContentControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: My existing code does work already; however, there are some scenarios where what I mentioned occurs, and instead of fully rendering the control, it only has empty space where the control is.

Answer (score 1):

I made a [quick project](https://github.com/shorstok/wpf-misc/tree/DataTemplateWpfTest) with your setup and everything seems to work. Error seems to be related with something done in your `CompactCustomEntityControl` / `FullCustomEntityControl` interacting with PresentationCore.

Try enabling .NET Framework source stepping in Debug->Options to see what's going on:

[image: setup screenshot]

Comment: Set all those options, used Microsoft Symbol server, still no source available.  Not sure how much help it would be to debug within the framework itself.

Comment: @Lunyx Try turning off default 'Microsoft Symbol Servers' in Options->Debugging->Symbols add https://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols as a source. Turning on .net framework debugging can be a little hassle because often mscorlib version doesnt match 'Microsoft Symbol Servers' sources version, but I think in your case that could help - you should see exact code that throws. In my experience this often helps with complex WPF problems

Comment: I set it up as you said, restarted VS, cleared the symbol cache, and tried debugging again.  It still seemed to try to load from Microsoft Symbol server  (MSSS) as a source, and when it got to the error line, it said no symbols loaded and gave the option between MSSS and the new link that you provided.  Chose the latter and it still says Source Not Available.  Am I doing something wrong still?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that there is no reliable solution to enable framework source stepping. The root cause is always that symbols version doesnt match debugged .dll version, but reasons can be different (even including Windows Update). Try checking off "require source files to exactly match the original version" option. Also this is supposed to work for .net >= 4.5.1 and vs >=2013 (but could work for earlier versions too).

Comment: Here's official MS manual that worked for me
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/setup.html

Comment: I've tried getting this to work for several hours, but it just refuses to.  It's ridiculous the hoops you have to jump through to try and debug a standard .NET dll.